# Dynamic Analysis with gdb on ELF binaries with no compilation/linking information

Tags: debugging, gdb, elf, dynamic-analysis

I am trying to do some dynamic analysis on a couple of ELF binaries with `gdb`. However, since those two are directly downloaded (ELF binary file only) with no additional information related to compilation/linking etc., I am not able to set up the proper environment in order to run them within `gdb`.

In particular, I am receiving the following errors:

- `warning: Error reading shared library list entry at 0x1600`
- `warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x804c7c0 != 0x7c`

Do you know how could I possibly resolve those issues or what can I do in order to set my environment properly for dynamic analysis?

Thank you so much in advance for all of your input.